# Custom table layout ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically show a table with a JSON element but in a format that is hard to do with tables. I'm using AngularJs 1.6.4 and Bootstrap but I'm kind of new at Angular. My JSON:-

```
"foo": {
    "name": "foo",
    "displayName": "FOO SHOW",
    "environments": [
        {
            "id": "one",
            "name": "PROD",
            "url": "http://my-prod-url.com"
        },
        {
            "id": "two",
            "name": "QA",
            "url": "http://my-qa-url.com"
        },
        {
            "id": "three",
            "name": "DEV",
            "url": "http://my-dev-url.com"
        }
    ]
},
"bar": {
    "name": "bar",
    "displayName": "BAR SHOW",
    "environments": [
        {
            "id": "four", 
            "name": "PROD",
            "url": "https://my-prod2-url.com"
        },
        {
            "id": "five",
            "name": "QA",
            "url": "https://my-uat2-url.com"
        },
        {
            "id": "six",
            "name": "DEV",
            "url": "https://my-dev2-url.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to display this in a way that dynamically shows everything but based on application on the top and environment on the left of a table. For example:-

```
ENV | FOO | BAR

PROD| fooProdUrl| barProdUrl

QA  | fooQaUrl| barQaUrl

DEV | fooDevUrl| barDevUrl
```

I've tried this but it's not dynamic and it doesn't display in the order I want:-

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Environment</th>
            <th class="text-center" data-ng-repeat="list in applications">{{list.displayName}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="text-center">
        <tr data-ng-repeat="list in applications">
            <th class="text-center">
                {{list.environments[0].name}} and {{list.name}}
            </th>
            <td>
                {{list.environments[0].url}} and {{list.name}} and {{list.environments[0].name}} 
            </td>
            <td>
                {{list.environments[1].url}} and {{list.name}} and {{list.environments[1].name}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This displays it in rows but not in the column way I want it.

Should I reorganize my `JSON` object? Split it in a different way? I've been stuck for a little bit on this.

Thanks!

Comment: is this what you looking for https://plnkr.co/edit/B3ukMnrtTgVJXYJZMzTr?p=preview

Comment: Super close. I want more like

ENV    | FOO                    | BAR /n

PROD | FOOPRODURL| BARPRODURL /n

QA      | FOOQAURL     |  BARQAURL /n

DEV    | FOODEVURL   | BARDEVURL /n

Comment: I went ahead and edited up above to reflect this better

Comment: glad that helped a bit